# How to loop through list and fadeIn with time intervals?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I have a standard list like this:

```
<ul>
<li style="display: none;">..</li>
<li style="display: none;">..</li>
<li style="display: none;">..</li>
</ul>
```

I want to fadeIn each element one at a time. How can I loop through each element and display it at 2 seconds apart? In other words, when the page loads the first element is displayed... 2 seconds later, then 2nd one is displayed, then another 2 seconds, then the 3rd is displayed, etc until they are all done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery built in [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) method

```
$('ul > li').each(function(i, element) {
    $(element).delay(i * 2000).fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion:

```
var $list = $('ul li');

(function loop(current) {    
    current && $(current).fadeIn('slow', function() {
        loop($list.splice(0,1));
    });
}($list.splice(0,1)));
```

**Demo**: http://www.jsfiddle.net/Ab8xW/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul > li').each(function(i, elem) {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $(elem).fadeIn();
    }, i * 2000);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/B94Fk/

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @ThiefMaster's approach:

```
function fadeInSequence(li){
    var next = $(li).next('li')!=null?function(){fadeInSequence($(li).next('li'));}:function(){};
    $(li).fadeIn(2000,next);
}
fadeInSequence($('ul>li:first'));
```

*(new guy, can't format code correctly...)*

Demo: http://www.jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/zdqCz/

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$('ul li').one('fader', function(e) {
    $(this).fadeIn(2000, function() {
        $(this).next().trigger('fader'); 
    });
}).first().trigger('fader');
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/redler/QNf29/1/